# How to get output message from db.Exec when executing SQL query with Go

Tags: postgresql, go, psql

I have a Postgres database, normally when you execute commands from psql you get some sort of an output like in the example bellow

```
test=> CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS algo;
NOTICE:  schema "algo" already exists, skipping
CREATE SCHEMA

test=> CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS algo2;
CREATE SCHEMA
```

I didn't find a way to get these output messages when using an sql client in go. The `db.Exec` function is returning `sql.Result` which has `LastInsertId` and `RowsAffected` but no output message. Is it possible to do it with sql client in go?

here is my Go code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+" dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, dbname, password)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    res, err := db.Exec("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS algo;")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    lastInsert, _ := res.LastInsertId()
    RoswAffected, _ := res.RowsAffected()
    fmt.Println(lastInsert, RoswAffected)
    // output: 0 0

}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `NOTICE` message ? You just need to change the query from `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS algo;` to `CREATE SCHEMA algo;`, then you can check the returned error.